# ¿Se usa la acepción negativa de "peliculón"?

Tags: significado, sustantivos, artes-visuales

Ayer me topé con una de esas palabras en el diccionario que contienen una acepción y su opuesta al mismo tiempo:

> **[peliculón](https://dle.rae.es/pelicul%C3%B3n)**
>
> 1. m. coloq. Película cinematográfica muy buena.
> 2. m. coloq. Película larga y aburrida.

La verdad es que esa segunda acepción me sorprendió, porque a mí solo se me ocurre usar dicha palabra en su acepción positiva. Veo que no tiene ninguna marca de localización, y los casos que he encontrado de ejemplo en el CREA me dan a entender que su uso es positivo en todos ellos. La única referencia que encuentro es la única ficha del Fichero General de la RAE acerca de esta palabra, que es de 1985 y ya contiene dicha acepción, por lo que es posible que la palabra en un principio tuviera un sentido negativo y se cambiara por el positivo.

¿Se usa realmente esa segunda acepción de *peliculón*? Y si es así, ¿está localizada en alguna región en particular?

Answer (score 3):

La segunda acepción de la palabra proviene de su uso como aumentativo. "Peliculón" es usado como el aumentativo más común de la palabra película, en lugar de términos potenciales como "peliculota", para hacer referencia a una película de mayor tamaño. El carácter peyorativo de esa segunda acepción probablemente originó del cambio histórico en la percepción social del cine, en el que las películas extensas se consideran aburridas (en contraste a la percepción pública del cine clásico, en el que las películas extensas frecuentemente eran películas épicas catalogadas como obras maestras).

Dicho eso, la acepción peyorativa de la palabra parece estar en desuso y desconozco si su utilización está concentrada en algún sitio determinado. Efectivamente el uso general de "peliculón" denota una acepción positiva o representa el aumentativo de la palabra, trasmitiendo el significado de mayor tamaño con naturaleza neutra.